# I have sample dataframe with null values, i want the null values to be shifted to the right side columnsvalues

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, rdd

Sample Input Dataframe:

```
+---+---+----+----+----+
|  A|  B|   C|   D|   E|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|  1|  2|   3|   4|   5|
|  6|  7|null|   8|   9|
| 10| 11|  12|null|null|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

Expected output dataframe:

```
+---+---+----+----+----+
|  A|  B|   C|   D|   E|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|  1|  2|   3|   4|   5|
|  6|  7|   8|   9|null|
| 10| 11|  12|null|null|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: You were better off the first time with it as text, just wrap the whole thing with ``` on its own line above and below the dataframe.

Comment: Yeah ! I am new here, now i have edited the question please check !

Comment: Looks much better!  I fixed the formatting up a little bit.  Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Spark at all, so I can't help you out with the question itself.

Comment: No Problem ! thanks for the edit !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var df = List(("1","2","3","4","5"),("6","7",null,"8","9"),("10","11","12",null,null),(null,"13",null,"14",null)).toDF("A","B","C","D","E")
df.show

+----+---+----+----+----+
|   A|  B|   C|   D|   E|
+----+---+----+----+----+
|   1|  2|   3|   4|   5|
|   6|  7|null|   8|   9|
|  10| 11|  12|null|null|
|null| 13|null|  14|null|
+----+---+----+----+----+

val cols = df.columns.size
df = df.withColumn("ct",split(concat_ws("-",df.columns.map(x=>col(x)):_*),"-"))
df.select((0 until cols).map(r => df.col("ct").getItem(r)): _*).toDF((0 until cols).map(r=>df.columns(r)):_*).show

+---+---+----+----+----+
|  A|  B|   C|   D|   E|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|  1|  2|   3|   4|   5|
|  6|  7|   8|   9|null|
| 10| 11|  12|null|null|
| 13| 14|null|null|null|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```